# Why can't I get Vue.js to display an image?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I can print the image URL, but I can't get the img tag to display it, though I think I've bound it correctly.

```js
<html>
<head>
  <title>Split VueJS Demo</title>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'vue'
    createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          image: 'http://www.cortazar-split.com/dog_origin.jpeg'
        }
      }
    }).mount('#app'); 
  </script>
</head>
<body> 
  <div>
    <div id="app">{{ image }}</div>
    <img id="app" :src="image"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't the img tag render the image at the provided URL?

Comment: I think your path should be directly in data()

Comment: You've placed `<img>` outside of `<div id="app"></div>`. Basically, your app doesn't have a template. As a side-note, having the same `id` more than once in a HTML document is invalid. It's down to each browser to decide how to handle it, since the HTML Standard states ids should be unique across a document. And even in the same browser, today you might get one behavior and tomorrow another.

Comment: Also be careful with http / https.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `img` tag inside the div with id="app".

You should never have the same `id` name used twice in your markup.

The `mount` method will use the first one found in your markup and ignore any subsequent elements with the same `id` name.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Split VueJS Demo</title>
  <script type="importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js"
      }
    }
  </script>

  <script type="module">
    import { createApp } from 'vue'

    const data = {
        image: 'http://www.cortazar-split.com/dog_origin.jpeg' 
      }
    console.log(data);
    createApp({
      data() {
        return data;
      }
    }).mount('#app'); 
  </script>

</head>
<body> 
  <div>
    <div id="app">
       {{ image }}
       <img :src="image"/>
    </div>
    <!-- This is outside the scope of the app: -->
    <!-- <img id="app" :src="image"/> -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```